# Internal layout of the iPad3

Tags: ipad

If you hold an iPad3 vertically, portrait, with the Apple logo right way up, which end is at the top?  the batteries or the main board?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from [one of iFixit's repair guides](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Installing+iPad+3+4G+Battery/8754/1#s38949), in portrait orientation with the home button at the bottom, the logic board is on the left side of the iPad, with the battery on the right.

[image: annotated iPad internals]

Comment: Thanks very much.  I've just realised that I was reading iPad 3G wrongly as iPad3, and was looking at this iFixit guide: http://www.iphone-spares.com/ipad-3g-teardown-disassembly   Now I understand why I was so confused.  Do you know where the charging port is on the picture that you posted?

Comment: You can't exactly see it, but it's on the bottom of the right half, basically directly below the camera, and where the home button would be if you folded the two halves back together.